# MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do [action]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs, mongoose-schema, mongodb-atlas

I have been looking for a solution to this error for ages and have tried all of the suggestions on this site already and still no luck. I am trying to create a website where the user can register so I want to save their credentials in a database. Here is a snippet of my Javascript code where I'm connecting to my database on Atlas:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");


const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://gettingstarted.owxpopb.mongodb.net/GettingStarted';

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB Atlas');
});
```

On my command line I get 'connected to MongoDB Atlas' so I know its connecting. This is my user schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  numberOfTickets: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});
```

But when I go to save the user's information/check them against the existing database using this code:

```
User.findOne({ email: newUser.email }, (err, existingUser) => {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }

    if (existingUser) {
      // A user with the same email address already exists
      return res.status(409).send({ message: 'Email address already registered' });
    }

    // If we reach here, it means the user details are not already in the database
    // You can proceed with saving the user to the database
    const newUser = new User(userSchema);
    newUser.save((err, savedUser) => {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal server error' });
      } else{
        res.render("home");
      }
      // User saved successfully
      return res.status(200).send(savedUser);
    });
  });
```

I get MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [GettingStarted.users] . I have tried updating my monoDB access in security to readWrite, made myself admin, checked that the node.js diver I'm using is compatible, and still I get this error. Can anyone help?

I have looked at solutions already posted on here but none seem to work.

Comment: The `dbURI` should contain the credentials, i.e username+password to connect to your MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it occured because I did not assign role the user in mongoDB. You need to assign the user role as atlasAdmin.

I had the same issue. My mongoDB was being connected and it showed in the console but I was unable to create a user.

Error I got:

> MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [find]

I followed the solution from the link [MongoError: user is not allowed to do action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649390/mongoerror-user-is-not-allowed-to-do-action)

I did the following steps

1. Open your mongoDB
2. Go to Database access
3. Click edit against the user
4. Expand the built in user roles
5. Click the roles dropdown
6. Select atlasAdmin

[Click Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEtDx.png)

[Expand Built in role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGghR.png)