# Unable to create database in cloud.mongo.db-user not allowed to create action

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoDB Compass, I created a cluster on cloud.mongo.db. Once the cluster was created,  I tried both "Read and Write to any database", and Atlas Admin for the built in roles. But when using either role, I am still unable to create a mongo db using MongoDB Compass, getting the following error "user is not allowed to do action [createCollection] on [testdb.smpleCol]".

Comment: What is the output of `db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 }).authInfo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: user is not allowed to do action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649390/mongoerror-user-is-not-allowed-to-do-action)

Comment: db.runCommand is a query right? Don't I need a database to query against. And that's the problem; I can't create a db.