# user is not allowed to do action in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working with Nodejs,I am using Expressjs,Right now i am tring to run project,Connection established successfully but whenever i try to use url (localhost:3001/api/plans) then i am getting following error in console

```
MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [git_flow.plans]
```

And i am getting following error in my browser

```
success false
ok  0
code    8000
codeName    "AtlasError"
```

Here is my "user-router.js" file

```
import express from 'express';
import * as UserCtrl from '../controllers/user-ctrl.js';
Const router = express.Router()
router.get('/github/auth/redirect', UserCtrl.redirectGithub)
router.post('/users', UserCtrl.createUser)
router.put('/user/:id', UserCtrl.updateUser)
export default router
Here is my controller file (user-ctrl.js) file code
export const redirectGithub = async (req, res) => {
  let code = req.query.code;
  console.log(req.query.code);
  if(!code) {
    return res.send({
      success: false,
      message: 'Error: no code'
    })
  }
  User.findOne({ githubAuthing: true }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
    }
    user.githubAuthing = false;
    user.code = code;

    console.log(user.redirect_uri);
    
    user
    .save()
    .then(() => {
        res.redirect(user.redirect_uri);
    })

  }).clone().catch(err => console.log(err))
}
H
```

ere is my model file,Where i am wrong ?

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const User = new Schema(
    {
        settings: { type: String, required: false },
        plan: { type: mongoose.ObjectId, required: false },
        introCompleted: { type: Number, required: false },
        session_id: { type: mongoose.ObjectId, required: true },
        githubToken: { type: String, required: false },
        githubUser: { type: Object, required: false },
        repo: { type: Object, required: false },
        shop: { type: String, required: false },
        githubAuthing: { type: Boolean, required: false },
        code: { type: String, required: false },
        redirect_uri: { type: String, required: false },
    },
    { timestamps: true },
)

export default mongoose.model('users', User)
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649390/mongoerror-user-is-not-allowed-to-do-action

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `save()` method with the mongoose findOne() returned user you have to pass the user data into the mongoose model and then you can use .save() like `new User(user).save()` as below mentioned can use it.

```
  User.findOne({ githubAuthing: true }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
    }
    user.githubAuthing = false;
    user.code = code;

    console.log(user.redirect_uri);

    new User(user).save()
    .then(() => {
        res.redirect(user.redirect_uri);
    })

  }).clone().catch(err => console.log(err))
```